# Resizing class according to screen size on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm new to flutter,I've designed my app using fixed dimensions.
What's the easiest way to resize scaffold according to screen size (different phone screen size).

Comment: You need to research first if you do not find this solution then post it here. Please read this article  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MediaQuery.of(context).size inside build method.

```
build(BuildContext) {
   final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
SizedBox(
   height: size.height,
   width: size.width * 0.85,
),
```

Another options are using external libraries like [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) or [ScreenUtils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

Answer (score 0):

You go through official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

And use **MediaQuery.of()** **Responsive, Adaptive** classes/Widgets

Answer (score 0):

To resize your screens/widgets you can use MediaQuery.

You can use it like ->

```
screenHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
screenWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Then you can scale it like ->

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.5,
)
```

If you multiply with 0.5, that means, you want to use 50% of screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Packages and sources  :

> https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework
> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive

You can check height and width by MediaQuery.
Example :

```
double _height =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double _width =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```